# Java - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java

I am facing an issue with my application.

I created a java application. And it is working without problems, but I wanna obfuscate it. For renaming classes I am  using ProGuard, so, i obfuscate it.

And getting the below  error:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  Native library <org/apache/culler/win32-x86-x64/jnidispatch.dll> not found in resource path 
  <file:C:/Users/MyCoolUsername/Desktop/awesomeapp.jar]>
```

But, without obfuscation it working without any problem. Also it happened if I use JName, and other obfuscators.

How to fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It looks like you just need to manually add the ".dll" file to the obfuscated JAR file.

Comment: @StephenC Uh, but where i can get it?

Comment: Huh?  If the non-obfuscated app is working ... as you say it is ... then you must already have the ".dll" file.  It will be in the "org.apache.culler" JAR file, I expect.